# Group By Contains [Date]

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by

I have a List where I make a group by on date values, and I would like to make an `if` statement on the group by item containing a DateNow, but I cant find it to work..

This is a sample of my Group By:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(v => new //here you count your total
    {
        Fecha = v.Fecha,
        Total = v.Total * v.Cantidad
    })
    .GroupBy(l => l.Fecha) //and then grouping
    .Select(z => new
    {
        Dia = z.Key,
        Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total)
    }))
{
    if (item.ToString().Contains(date))
    {  
        <input value="@item" />
    }
}
```

And it give me this Output:

```
{ Dia = 1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM, Total = 40293.0000 }
{ Dia = 1/3/2016 12:00:00 AM, Total = 96774.0000 }
{ Dia = 2/12/2016 12:00:00 AM, Total = 34374.0000 }
```

and I want a `if` statement that only give me the group by of Today in the example above I would like the if to only give me this output:

```
{ Dia = 2/12/2016 12:00:00 AM, Total = 34374.0000 }
```

but my "`if (item.ToString().Contains(date))`" don't work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `Where()` part to get only records agains today like:

```
.GroupBy(l => l.Fecha)
.Where(x=> x.Key.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
.......................
.......................
```

or:

```
if (item.Dia.Date == DateTime.Today)
{
   <input value="@item" />
}
```

Comment: Could use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Comment: Thanks @juharr for telling, did'nt knew about that property

Comment: but my item is a group by it wont be exactly == to the DateTime.Today shouldnt i use a contains or something like that?

Comment: you have a property which is DateTime, you can check with equality check

Comment: are you trying to check if groupby result has any record with today Date?

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to check if one of my group by items have a date value of Today date then it should make the input but my if never enters like it never contains today date even so it does contains it@EhsanSajjad

Comment: have you tried the if condition i posted it should work for you, you can check Dates with equality, ``==`` is overloaded for ``DateTime`` type

Comment: Got it it really worked the if statemnt Thank you very much @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 0):

You can use a where statement like this:

```
Where(x=> x.Key.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
```